# Screen tearing on Intel® HD Graphics 3000 (SNB GT2)

Tags: screen, intel, tearing

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have edited the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf like most tutorials suggest and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: Can you share a little bit what did you put on the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf ?